# Set Env var in before_script - access in after_script Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to set an env var in a gitlab `before_script` then access it in the `after_script`. Is this possible?

```
default:
  before_script:
    - FOO=bar
  after_script:
    - echo "FOO is $FOO"

job1:
  script:
    - sleep 2
```

I'm expecting output to be: `"FOO is bar"` but I get `FOO is`

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from @thiagocsf@techhub.social on Mastodon.

No, it's not possible. `before_script` and `after_script` run in different shells.

However, you can do this:

```
before_script:
  - echo FOO=BAR >> vars.env

after_script:
  - source vars.env .
  - echo "Foo is $FOO"      # This works: "Foo is BAR"
```